# My css is messing with the scrolling working properly

Tags: html, css

I have this setup https://codepen.io/saraLance/pen/LYGevXW and I have a couple of problems.

1. the `header` covers more than the parent width.
2. Scroll works weird, it seems to stop after the button `play`, and then I have to scroll again.

I have tried to fix the scroll problem making the `header` fixed `position: fixed; width: 100%` but the `header` covers more than the parent div.

I also have no idea why `screen` height it's not the same that it's parent `screens`.

Ideally `sit-container` should be after `header` and `header` should be fixed.

```css
div {
  width: auto;
}

.screens {
  background: green;
  height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  overflow-y: auto;
}

.screen {
  background: red;
}

.header {
  border: solid 1px black;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-evenly;
  padding: 12px;
  background: white;
}

.sit-container {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  padding-top: 1rem;
  overflow: auto;
}

.strip {
  width: 100vw;
}

.view {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: nowrap;
  overflow-x: auto;
  -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
  min-height: 300px;
  min-width: 300px;
  animation-delay: 0.2s;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.view-1 {
  height: 300px;
  width: 300px;
  flex: 0 0 auto;
  margin: 0 auto;
  margin-top: 1rem;
  border: solid 1px black;
}

.button-section {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  text-align: center;
  margin-top: 1rem;
  width: 100%;
}

.play-button {
  height: 1.25rem;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  color: black;
  border: 1px solid black;
  text-decoration: none;
  padding: 1rem 1.25rem;
  line-height: 1rem;
  border-radius: 0.375rem;
  font-size: 1rem;
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: normal;
  text-align: center;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  margin: 1rem;
}

.quit-button {
  color: black;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 1.2rem;
  margin-top: 1.5rem;
  margin-bottom: 1.5rem;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=">
  <title></title>
</head>

<body>

  <div class="screens">
    <div class="screen">
      <div class="header">
        <div class="div-1">Div-1</div>
        <div class="div-1">Div-2</div>
      </div>
      <div class="sit-container">
        <div class="strip">
          <div class="view">
            <div class="view-1">View-1</div>
            <div class="view-1">View-2</div>
            <div class="view-1">View-3</div>
            <div class="view-1">View-4</div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="button-section">
          <a class="play-button">Play</a>
          <a class="quit-button">Quit</a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

`screens` class should be `width: auto` and `overflow-x:hidden` should be on `button-section`

See output in full screen

```css
div {
  width: auto;
}

@media (min-width: 768px) {
  width:35%;
  margin:auto;
}

.screens {
  background: green;
  height:"auto";
  display: flex;
}

.screen {
  background: red;
}

.header {
  border: solid 1px black;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-evenly;
  padding: 12px;
  background: white;
}

.sit-container {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  padding-top: 1rem;
  overflow: auto;
}

.strip {
  width: 100vw;
  @media (min-width: 768px) {
    width: 35vw;
  }
}

.view {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: nowrap;
  overflow-x: auto;
  -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
  min-height: 300px;
  min-width: 300px;
  animation-delay: 0.2s;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.view-1{
  height: 300px;
  width: 300px;
  flex: 0 0 auto;
  margin: 0 auto;
  margin-top: 1rem;
  border: solid 1px black;
}

.button-section{  
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  text-align: center;
  margin-top: 1rem;
  width: 100%;
  overflow-x:hidden;
}

.play-button {
  height: 1.25rem;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  color: black;
  border: 1px solid black;
  text-decoration: none;
  padding: 1rem 1.25rem;
  line-height: 1rem;
  border-radius: 0.375rem;
  font-size: 1rem;
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: normal;
  text-align: center;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  margin: 1rem;
}

.quit-button {
  color: black;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 1.2rem;
  margin-top: 1.5rem;
  margin-bottom: 1.5rem;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<div class="screens">
  <div class="screen">
    <div class="header">
      <div class="div-1">Div-1</div>
      <div class="div-1">Div-2</div>
    </div>
    <div class="sit-container">
      <div class="strip">
        <div class="view">
          <div class="view-1">View-1</div>
          <div class="view-1">View-2</div>
          <div class="view-1">View-3</div>
          <div class="view-1">View-4</div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="button-section">
        <a class="play-button">Play</a>
        <a class="quit-button">Quit</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```